# Using BeautifulSoup to loop through a list and create XML tags

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I have a list of years, as follows:

```
year = ['2005', '2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012', '2013']
```

I am trying to create a series of XML tags enclosed within another pre-existing tag, like so:

```
<intro>
    <exposures>
      <exposure year = "2005"></exposure>
      <exposure year = "2006"></exposure>
      <exposure year = "2007"></exposure>
      <exposure year = "2008"></exposure>
      etc.
    <exposures> 
</intro>
```

Later on I'll populate things within the tags. Right now I'm trying to loop through `year` and add them to the  tag and then enclose it within the  tag.

I've been trying to loop through the 'year' list and append each value to the  tag as an attribute:

```
testsoup = BeautifulSoup(testxml, 'xml')
intro_tag = testsoup.intro('intro')
exp_tag = testsoup.exposures('exposures')
year = ['2005', '2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012', '2013']
exposure_tag = testsoup.new_tag('exposure', year = '')
for x in year:    
    exposure_tag['year'] = x
    exp_tag.append(exposure_tag)
    intro_tag.append(exp_tag)
```

Unfortunately this only seems to append the last value in the list:

```
<intro><exposures><exposure year="2013"/></exposures></intro>
```

Is this just a feature of BeautifulSoup? Can you only add one tag and not multiple ones? I'm using BeautifulSoup 4.4.0.

Incidentally, is BeautifulSoup the best way to do this? I see a lot of posts praising BS4 and lxml for their webscraping abilities but neither seem to be useful for generating XML (that's not a bad thing, just something I've noticed). Is there a better package for automating XML generation?

Comment: Which version of BeautifulSoup are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that the issue is this line: `exposure_tag = testsoup.new_tag('exposure', year = '')`. You have one tag and you are trying to append it to the same parent multiple times. Try this instead.

```
for x in year:    
    exposure_tag = testsoup.new_tag('exposure', year = x)
    exp_tag.append(exposure_tag)
    intro_tag.append(exp_tag)
```

Comment: Oh, I see. If it's nested in the loop, then each time I loop through it, a new tag is created. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

I have not looked into BS source code, but think the behaviour is this: when you calling `exp_tag.append(smth)` you actually add pointer to `smth` object. So as you instantiate `exposure_tag` only once, you got bunch of pointers to the same object. When you modify that object in `exposure_tag['year'] = x`, it affects all elements of internal list structure of BS.

So, the solution is to create new object instance in every step:

```
testsoup = BeautifulSoup(testxml, 'xml')
intro_tag = testsoup.intro('intro')
exp_tag = testsoup.exposures('exposures')
year = ['2005', '2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012', '2013']
for x in year:    
    exposure_tag = testsoup.new_tag('exposure', year = x)
    exp_tag.append(exposure_tag)
    intro_tag.append(exp_tag)  # BTW: Are you sure you need this here?
```